# Script Remove desire XML Tags

Tags: xml, bash

I do have next XML body,

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageReportsInPubFolders</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageRoles</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageSandboxes</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageSelfService</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageSharing</name>
</userPermissions>
```

I want to remove:

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageSandboxes</name>
</userPermissions>
```

So desire output:

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageReportsInPubFolders</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageRoles</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageSelfService</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageSharing</name>
</userPermissions>
```

I have tried the following command:

sed -i '' '//,/</userPermissions>/d', but it removes all userPermissions tags, I dont need this. Please let me know your thoughts/

Comment: The XML sample is not **well-formed**, it is missing a root tag. How about XSLT based solution?

Comment: Your question is unclear: **why** do you want to delete that specific `<userPermissions>`? Is it because it's the third element or because it has a `<name>ManageSandboxes</name>` child?

Comment: <Profile>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageReportsInPubFolders</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageRoles</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageSelfService</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageSharing</name>
</userPermissions>
</Profile>

Answer (score 2):

You can't parse XML with regex, and `sed` is not an XML-parser! I suggest you use the right tools for the job at hand; [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel), or [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet).

```
$ xidel -s input.xml \
  -e 'x:replace-nodes(//userPermissions[name="ManageSandboxes"],())' \
  --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent
```

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -O -d '//userPermissions[name="ManageSandboxes"]' input.xml
```

Output in both cases:

```
<Profile>
  <userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageReportsInPubFolders</name>
  </userPermissions>
  <userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageRoles</name>
  </userPermissions>
  <userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageSelfService</name>
  </userPermissions>
  <userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageSharing</name>
  </userPermissions>
</Profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that does the trick:

```
sed "/<userPermissions>/,/<\/userPermissions>/ {
  N
  N
  N
  /.*ManageSandboxes.*/d
}"
```

Please note each of the commands needs to be in a new line in order for this to work.

In short, I'm appending the next 3 lines to the current pattern space and checking if "ManageSandboxes" is anywhere in my 4-lines-in-1 line and if so it deletes all of it.

If you would like to learn more about sed [here](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-24) is a very good guide.

Comment: I have tried sed "/<userPermissions>/,/<\/userPermissions>/ {
  N
  N
  N
  /.*ManageSandboxes.*/d
}"

But it also deletes the parent tag at the bottom

Comment: well you can play with the amount of lines appended, remove the 'd' at the end for testing but in any case if you insist on using the single line format you need to add ';' like so: "/<userPermissions>/,/<\/userPermissions>/ { N; N; N; /.*ManageSandboxes.*/d ;}"

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the metadata for a Salesforce Profile, you can use [force-md](https://github.com/ForceCLI/force-md/) to remove the permission:

```
$ force-md profile user-permissions delete -p ManageSandboxes src/profiles/Admin.profile
```